# Koajs, simple app not running on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

Following this basic tutorial on Youtube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVkTv-NOpiQ

By localhost:3000 or :4444 isn't working, nothing showing up in browser or in post man. **Not Found.**

My app

```
const Koa = require('koa'),
      Router = require('koa-router')

const app = new Koa(),
      router = new Router()

let users = [
  {
    name: 'Leon Gaban',
    email: 'quxquz@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'Juan Gonzales',
    email: 'foobaz@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'Foo Bar',
    email: 'foobar@gmail.com'
  }
]

// ? Home Route
// router.get('/')

// ? GET user
router.get('/user:id', ctx => {
  ctx.body = users[ctx.params.id]
})

app
  .use(router.allowedMethods())
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(require('koa-body')())

app.listen(4444)
```

Thoughts? Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: you forgot "/" hahah.
router.get('/user:id', ctx => 

will be
router.get('/user/:id', ctx =>

Comment: Use sample here
https://github.com/ZijianHe/koa-router

Comment: @xdeepakv ah yes you're right, you want to post the correct answer?

Comment: I have posted, Please dont down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the routing. It works

```
const Koa = require('koa'),
      Router = require('koa-router')

const app = new Koa(),
      router = new Router()

let users = [
  {
    name: 'Leon Gaban',
    email: 'quxquz@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'Juan Gonzales',
    email: 'foobaz@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'Foo Bar',
    email: 'foobar@gmail.com'
  }
]

// ? Home Route
router.get('/', ctx => {
  ctx.body = "test"
})

// ? GET user
router.get('/user/:id',  ctx => {
  ctx.body = users[ctx.params.id]
})

app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods())
  .use(require('koa-body')())

app.listen(4444)
```